# Appium showing error "unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 31.0.1650.59\n even though the chrome version is higher in the Android mobile app

Tags: android, appium

I have been trying to use Appium v1.1.0  to test a hybrid app in WebView in Android 4.4.3(Nexus 4)  . The chrome version on Nexus 4 is - 35.0.1916.141 .
But the Appium server is throwing an error stating that

Chrome version must be >= 31.0.1650.59\n .

This is the error from the Appium Node server

"info: Spawning chromedriver with: C:\AppiumForWindows\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\chromedriver\windows\chromedriver.exe

> info: [CHROMEDRIVER] Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 9515
>   info: Making http request with opts: {","method":"POST","json":{"sessionId":null,"desiredCapabilities":{"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.spoonity.consumer.android.spoonityandroid","androidUseRunningApp":true,"androidDeviceSerial":"017c991520d26945"}}}}
>   ERROR: error: Chromedriver create session did not work. Status was 200 and body was {"sessionId":"16ecce432155bc0bb7be243a865affa2","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 31.0.1650.59\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)"}}
>   info: Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver)","origValue":"Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver"},"sessionId":"907d23de-8820-4f8c-ab62-923b77c36e13"}
>   POST /wd/hub/session/907d23de-8820-4f8c-ab62-923b77c36e13/context 500 1103ms - 308b"

Answer (score 2):

4.4 Kit Kat runs chrome version 30 in a hybrid app which is lower than 31.  I'm running into this same issue.  This issue should be reported to the appium team as they might need to downgrade to a different chromedriver that supports versions of chrome on version 30.

Related post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/Wlc_HFwIgTc

It also looks like it's a chrome driver issue and it's related to upgrading device to 4.4.3.  Downgrading solves the issue but is not an option for me.